# Angular JS fires ng-click before loading the resource at href

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a link/anchor HTML like:

```
<a href='/some-form' ng-click='someFunction(item)'>Text</a>
```

What I have in mind is that user clicks this link, then I want to load an HTML from server, and after the loading of that HTML, I want `someFunction` to be executed, which fills the loaded form with some data.

However, by debugging my code, it seems that Angular JS first fires `someFunction` function, and then browser loads the HTML. Not only I want this to be reverse, but also I need them to be executed sequentially (synchronously).

Is my design a good design? Is there any other way to achieve this behavior? If not, what should I do to make it work?

Answer (score 3):

so I think `someFunction(item)` should be in the other controller dealing with the route `/some-form`.

You may also consider using `$location` to manually navigate to `/some-form`.

Comment: Sounds very good, but actually it doesn't help! I think it's cause the controller is loaded before the HTML, While I need the DOM to be ready and then add the data to the form using 'someFunction(item)'.

btw. 'someFunction(item)' is inside a controller that is dealing with the routing